# Remove substring within aggregate

Tags: sql, netezza

I am working in a data warehouse and combining 3 columns with the following:

```
CAST(
    ISNULL(PORCH_TYPE_1,'') || 
    CASE WHEN PORCH_TYPE_2 IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ', ' END || 
    ISNULL(PORCH_TYPE_2,'') || 
    CASE WHEN PORCH_TYPE_3 IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ', ' END || 
    ISNULL(PORCH_TYPE_3,'') AS VARCHAR(250)
    ) AS PORCH_TYPE,
```

This is working, except in the results, I can end up with something that looks like:

> Open Porch, None, None

or

> None, None, Open Porch

What I'm needing to do is remove both

> None

and

> ,None

How would I go about doing that within this same column/statement?

Answer (score 1):

One method is to concatenate the comma to the end of each valid porch type.  Then remove the final trailing comma using `TRIM()`:

```
TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM
      ((CASE WHEN PORCH_TYPE_1 <> 'None' THEN PORCH_TYPE_1 || ',' END) || 
       (CASE WHEN PORCH_TYPE_2 <> 'None' THEN PORCH_TYPE_2 || ',' END) || 
       (CASE WHEN PORCH_TYPE_3 <> 'None' THEN PORCH_TYPE_3 || ',' END)
      )
```

Comment: I am getting compile errors trying to implement this (but it is not telling me what it is). Where do I put this in relation to the sql in the question?

Comment: This would replace the entire `CASE` statement.